# google map with android

Tags: google-maps

my application includes simple google map and I registered the key and I got api there's no problem if I install the app by cmd command after using export signed app package, but if I run the app directly from eclipse it will show an empty grid without map on my android phone .
What can I do , Please anybody help me

Comment: are you using 2 different keytools for signing ? (a real keytool you use for the playstore and the one provided by eclipse ?)

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the google api console ? There you can only use one key. If you use the key by your signed certificate, you cant use the key over eclipse. Eclipse APKs are signed by debug certificate, in which the key would not fit to debug.